# Windows IoT Core GpioController - assembly 'Windows' causes a cycle

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, namespaces, .net-assembly, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying my new Raspberry Pi with Windows 10 IoT Core.

I have fallowed the steps of the installations and cofigurations, and every thing was fine until I've got to Blanky tutorial

http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/Blinky.htm

I am trying to get GpioController instance in my universal app:

```
var gpioController = Windows.Devices.Gpio.GpioController.getDefault();
```

And I am getting two errors:

> Error CS0731  The type forwarder for type
>   'Windows.Devices.Gpio.GpioController' in assembly 'Windows' causes a
>   cycle IOT.POC C:\Users\Pavel\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\IOT.POC\IOT.POC\MainPage.xaml.cs    26
>
> Error CS1069  The type name 'GpioController' could not be found in the
>   namespace 'Windows.Devices.Gpio'. This type has been forwarded to
>   assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' Consider adding a
>   reference to that assembly.   IOT.POC C:\Users\Pavel\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2015\Projects\IOT.POC\IOT.POC\MainPage.xaml.cs 26

However, when I am adding the using for the namespace:

```
using Windows.Devices.Gpio;
```

I don't get any errors at all...

I also don't the namespace Windows.Devices.Gpio under Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract  namespace...

Any ideas?

Comment: Its possible the tutorial was written for a pre-release version of IoT Core and something changed in the interface.

Comment: That's could be great, how do you access the GPIO then? All the information on the web that I can find talkisabout that implementation.

Comment: I've got an answer on raspberry pi Stack Exchange: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38177/windows-iot-core-gpiocontroller-assembly-windows-causes-a-cycle